# Will search engines honor robots.txt for a separate site that is a virtual directory under another site?

Tags: robots.txt

I have a website (Ex: www.examplesite.com), and I am creating another site as a separate, stand-alone site in IIS. This second site's URL will make it look like it's part of my main site: www.examplesite.com/anothersite. This is accomplished by creating a virtual directory under my main site that points to the second site.

I am allowing my main site (www.examplesite.com) to be indexed in search engines, but I do **not** want my second, virtual directory site to be seen by search engines. Can I allow my second site to have its own robots.txt file, and disallow all pages for that site there?  Or do I need to modify my main site's robots.txt file and tell it to disallow the virtual directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an own robots.txt for directories. Only a "host" can have it's own robots.txt: example.com, www.example.com, sub.example.com, sub.sub.example.com, …

So if you want to set rules for `www.example.com/anothersite`, you have to use the robots.txt at `www.example.com/robots.txt`.

If you want to block *all* pages of the sub-site, simply add:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /anothersite
```

This will block all URL paths that *start* with "anothersite". E.g. these links are all blocked then:

- `www.example.com/anothersite`
- `www.example.com/anothersite.html`
- `www.example.com/anothersitefoobar`
- `www.example.com/anothersite/foobar`
- `www.example.com/anothersite/foo/bar/`
- …

Note: If your robots.txt already contains `User-agent: *`, you'd have to add the `Disallow` line in this block instead of adding a new block (bots will stop reading the robots.txt as soon as they found a block that matches for them).